# Representación gráfica de Nodos en C++

Tags: c++

Tengo esta "típica" clase Nodo :

```
class Nodo
{
    public:
        int x;
        int y;
        std::string nombre;
        Nodo* arriba;
        Nodo* abajo;
        Nodo* izquierda;
        Nodo* derecha;
        Nodo* siguiente;
        Nodo();
        Nodo(int i, int j, std::string s);
        ~Nodo();

        void Set_Adyacentes();
        void Mostrar_Adyacentes();
        void Mostrar_Mapa();
    protected:
    private:
        static const int ANCHO = 20;
        static const int ALTO  = 20;
        char mapa[ALTO][ANCHO];
Nodo::Nodo()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    nombre = "";
    arriba    = NULL;
    abajo     = NULL;
    izquierda = NULL;
    derecha   = NULL;
    siguiente = NULL;
    for(int j = 0; j < ALTO; j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < ANCHO; k++)
        {
            mapa[j][k] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

Nodo::Nodo(int i, int j, std::string s)
{
    x = i;
    y = j;
    nombre = s;
    arriba    = NULL;
    abajo     = NULL;
    izquierda = NULL;
    derecha   = NULL;
    siguiente = NULL;
}

Nodo::~Nodo()
{
    arriba    = 0;
    abajo     = 0;
    izquierda = 0;
    derecha   = 0;
    siguiente = 0;
    delete arriba;
    delete abajo;
    delete izquierda;
    delete derecha;
    delete siguiente;
}

void Nodo::Set_Adyacentes()
{
    if(y - 1 >= 0)
    {
        arriba = new Nodo(x, y - 1, "Nodo arriba");
        siguiente = arriba;
        mapa[arriba->y][arriba->x] = '*';
    }
    if(y + 1 < ALTO)
    {
        abajo = new Nodo(x, y + 1, "Nodo abajo");
        siguiente = abajo;
        mapa[abajo->y][abajo->x] = '*';
    }
    if(x + 1 < ANCHO)
    {
        derecha = new Nodo(x + 1, y, "Nodo derecho");
        siguiente = derecha;
        mapa[derecha->y][derecha->x] = '*';
    }
    if(x - 1 >= 0)
    {
        izquierda = new Nodo(x - 1, y, "Nodo izquierdo");
        siguiente = izquierda;
        mapa[izquierda->y][izquierda->x] = '*';
    }
}

void Nodo::Mostrar_Mapa()
{
    for(int j = 0; j < ALTO; j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < ANCHO; k++)
        {
            std::cout << mapa[j][k];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

y mi intención es representar gráficamente cada nodo que exista con un asterisco (*) por la consola. Para ello voy pidiendo al usuario que decida hacia que dirección moverse y si existe se crea el nodo y su correspondiente representación gráfica, o esa es la teoría. En la práctica solo se representa un punto y además siempre el mismo. Estoy bastante perdido. Agradezco de corazón cualquier pista que me podais dar. Esta es la función main :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Nodo.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool salir = false;
    char opcion = ' ';
    Nodo* Mi_Nodo = new Nodo(0, 0, "Mi nodo");
    Mi_Nodo->Set_Adyacentes();

    Nodo* auxiliar = Mi_Nodo->siguiente;

    while(!salir)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\n 1.- Arriba";
        cout << "\n 2.- Abajo";
        cout << "\n 3.- Izquierda";
        cout << "\n 4.- Derecha";
        cout << "\n 5.- Salir\n";
        cout << "\n Opcion : ";
        cin >> opcion;

        switch(opcion)
        {
        case '1':
        {
            if(Mi_Nodo->arriba != NULL)
            {
                Mi_Nodo->arriba->Set_Adyacentes();
                auxiliar = Mi_Nodo->arriba;
                cout << " Auxiliar apunta a " << auxiliar->arriba->nombre;
                cout << " X = " << auxiliar->x << " Y = " << auxiliar->y << endl;
                Mi_Nodo->Mostrar_Mapa();
            }
            else cout << " No se puede ir arriba\n";
            system("pause");
        }
        break;
        case '2':
        {
            if(Mi_Nodo->abajo != NULL)
            {
                Mi_Nodo->abajo->Set_Adyacentes();
                auxiliar = Mi_Nodo->abajo;
                cout << " Auxiliar apunta a " << Mi_Nodo->abajo->nombre;
                cout << " X = " << auxiliar->x << " Y = " << auxiliar->y << endl;
                Mi_Nodo->Mostrar_Mapa();
            }
            else cout << " No se puede ir abajo\n";
            system("pause");
        }
        break;
        case '3':
        {
            if(Mi_Nodo->izquierda != NULL)
            {
                Mi_Nodo->izquierda->Set_Adyacentes();
                auxiliar = Mi_Nodo->izquierda;
                cout << " Auxiliar apunta a " << Mi_Nodo->izquierda->nombre;
                cout << " X = " << auxiliar->x << " Y = " << auxiliar->y << endl;
                Mi_Nodo->Mostrar_Mapa();
            }
            else cout << " No se puede ir a la izquierda\n";
            system("pause");
        }
        break;
        case '4':
        {
            if(Mi_Nodo->derecha != NULL)
            {
                Mi_Nodo->derecha->Set_Adyacentes();
                auxiliar = Mi_Nodo->derecha;
                cout << " Auxiliar apunta a " << Mi_Nodo->derecha->nombre;
                cout << " X = " << auxiliar->x << " Y = " << auxiliar->y << endl;;
                Mi_Nodo->Mostrar_Mapa();
            }
            else cout << " No se puede ir a la derecha\n";
            system("pause");
        }
        break;
        case 'S':
        default :
        {
            cout << " Nos vemos\n";
            salir = true;
        }
        break;
        }
    }
    Mi_Nodo = 0;
    delete Mi_Nodo;
    auxiliar = 0;
    delete auxiliar;
    return 0;
}
```

Como siempre mil gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Gráficamente como debería salirte en consola, un ejemplo.

Comment: @Hoscanoa Debería imprimir un asterisco en cada dirección que elija el usuario. Si estamos en la posición 0, 0 solo se puede ir a la derecha o abajo por lo tanto si se elige derecha debería imprimir algo así : **

Comment: Y si desde ahí se volviera a elegir ir a la derecha : *** . Espero estar explicándome bien.

Comment: Algún error que te salga?

Comment: @Hoscanoa Compila y funciona pero no con los resultados esperados. Siempre se representa el asterisco inicial que es el nodo de coordenada 0, 0 pero no se representan los demás a medida que el usuario va "avanzando" con sus elecciones.

Comment: No se como escribirlo en un comentario, no me deja bajar de línea sin darle a 'enter' y publicarlo, pero lo que se imprime por consola siempre es * y otro asterisco por debajo y a la izquierda del primero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Estoy bastante perdido

Los perdidos somos nostros. Para empezar esta afirmación es incorrecta:

> Tengo esta "típica" clase Nodo

De *típica* no tiene absolutamente nada. Tiene importantes errores de diseño. El más importante es el que trata sobre las responsabilidades. Cada nodo reprensenta un nodo, un mapeador de nodos y los datos de cada nodo, como puedes ver en el siguiente código:

```
class Nodo
{
    // Valores del nodo
    int x;
    int y;
    std::string nombre;

    // Nodo
    Nodo* arriba;
    Nodo* abajo;
    Nodo* izquierda;
    Nodo* derecha;
    Nodo* siguiente;

    // mapeo de nodos
    static const int ANCHO = 20;
    static const int ALTO  = 20;
    char mapa[ALTO][ANCHO];
};
```

En tu caso el problema se encuentra en el mapeo de los nodos. Este sistema está montado de forma de que cada nodo tiene un mapa diferente. Si tu creas un nodo y después le añades un nodo a la derecha al final obtendrás dos mapas y cada uno con información diferente. ¿A cual le preguntas de los dos?

La solución pasa por sacar el mapeo de los nodos fuera de la clase `Nodo`. No hay una regla que determine cómo debe implementarse el mecanismo de mapeo, pero lo que está claro es que el mismo debería garantizar que la malla quede correctamente cosida.

Si suponemos que los nodos van a formar una especie de cuadrícula el mapeo podría quedar algo así:

```
class Mapa
{
  int alto;
  int ancho;
  Nodo** mapa;

  Nodo*& Get(int x, int y) const
  { return mapa[x*ancho+y]; }

public:

  Mapa(int alto, int ancho)
    : mapa(new Nodo*[alto*ancho]),
      alto(alto),
      ancho(ancho)
  {
    std::memset(mapa,0,alto*ancho*sizeof(int));
  }

  ~Mapa()
  {
    for( int i=0; i<ancho; i++)
    {
      for( int j=0; j<alto; j++ )
        delete Get(i,j);
    }

    delete[] mapa;
  }

  void SetNodo(int x, int y, std::string const& valor)
  {
    Nodo*& nodo = Get(x,y);

    if( nodo == nullptr )
    {
      nodo = new Nodo(x,y,valor);

      if( y>0 )
      {
        Nodo* vecino = Get(x,y-1);
        nodo->arriba = vecino;

        if( vecino )
          vecino->abajo = nodo;
      }

      if( y<alto-1 )
      {
        Nodo* vecino = Get(x,y+1);
        nodo->abajo = vecino;

        if( vecino )
        vecino->arriba = nodo;
      }

      if( x>0 )
      {
        Nodo* vecino = Get(x-1,y);
        nodo->izquierda = vecino;

        if( vecino )
          vecino->derecha = nodo;
      }

      if( x < ancho-1 )
      {
        Nodo* vecino = Get(x+1,y);
        nodo->derecha = vecino;

        if( vecino )
          vecino->izquierda = nodo;
      }
    }
    else
      nodo->nombre= valor;
  }

  void Imprimir() const
  {
    for( int i=0; i<ancho; i++ )
    {
      for( int j=0; j<alto; j++ )
      {
        Nodo* nodo = Get(i,j);
        if( nodo == nullptr )
          std::cout << "  ";
        else
          std::cout << "* ";
      }

      std::cout << '\n';
    }
  }
};
```

Con esto la clase `Nodo` puede quedar reducida a algo así:

```
struct Nodo
{
  int x;
  int y;
  std::string nombre;

  Nodo* arriba;
  Nodo* abajo;
  Nodo* izquierda;
  Nodo* derecha;

  Nodo(int x,int y,std::string const& nombre)
    : x(x),
      y(y),
      nombre(nombre),
      arriba(nullptr),
      abajo(nullptr),
      izquierda(nullptr),
      derecha(nullptr)
  { }
};
```

Y ahora un pequeño código para probar la funcionalidad:

```
int main()
{
  Mapa mapa(10,10);

  mapa.SetNodo(1,1,"a");
  mapa.SetNodo(1,2,"b");
  mapa.SetNodo(1,3,"c");
  mapa.SetNodo(2,2,"d");
  mapa.SetNodo(9,9,"e");

  mapa.Imprimir();
}
```

Salida:

```
  * * *
    *






                  *
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder @eferion. `Tiene importantes errores de diseño` : has sido muy generoso, más que importantes son garrafales. Me cuesta mucho ver las relaciones entre las clases. Tengo que estudiar más, está claro.

Comment: `mapa(new Nodo*[alto*ancho])` ¿esto es equivalente a `mapa(new Nodo*[alto][ancho])` ?.

Comment: Y esto no me acaba de quedar claro : `std::memset(mapa,0,alto*ancho*sizeof(int));`. Entiendo que es para inicializar los elementos del mapa a 0, pero si es así, ¿sería igual si se usa el constructor de la clase **Nodo** para hacerlo de esta forma ? : `Nodo::Nodo()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    nombre = "";
    arriba    = NULL;
    abajo     = NULL;
    izquierda = NULL;
    derecha   = NULL;
    siguiente = NULL;
    for(int j = 0; j < ALTO; j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < ANCHO; k++)
        {
            mapa[j][k] = ' ';
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @Battyhal `mapa(new Nodo*[alto*ancho])` con esa linea reservo espacio para todos los nodos de una sola vez. En vez de una matriz al uso, que requiere una reserva para las filas y otro por cada columna, veo mas práctico hacerlo así

Comment: @Battyhal sí es equivalente, pero cuanto menos codigo escribas menos codigo tendrás que mantener en el futuro. Eso y que aprovechas cosas echas por gente que sabe más que tu

Comment: @eferionAsí lo haré. Muchas gracias.